# Cite on line with NatBib in LyX with apacite package

Tags: lyx, natbib, apa6, apacite

I'm writing my thesis with LyX in Basque (a language that has declensions of proper nouns, such as authors). In my master's they told me to write the references in the APA, 6th edition, style. I want to cite the author in the text many times, to be able to express the name with the necessary declined form.

For the references like APA: My preamble has `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` and I'm trying to translate `apacite` to Basque.

But to put the cite in the text in LyX:
If `settings>bibliography>default` I can't choose how to put `(author, year)`, `author`, `year`, ... `(year)`; only I can put `(author, year)`. It is a problem in Basque, because I need to write something after the author name, like ***autorby* (year)**

And if I choose `settings>bibliography>NatBib (autor,year)` I can't compile very well. The error says `Too many }'s.` (and more).

How can I choose the `natbib` options in-text?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem. I'm curious though, are you using the Basque interface in LyX? (meaning, does it say "Fitxategia" as the menu option in the upper-left)? Our translation is 70 to 80% done. If you are interested in contributing a few translations, we would really appreciate it, but I understand if you need to instead focus on your master's thesis :). In case you are interested, write to lyx-docs@lists.lyx.org and we can explain how it would work.

Comment: Yes, I'm using LyX with Basque interface (fitxategia & co.) And yes, I need to be focused in the doctor thesis...  If my whife and sons leave me making and not leave me :_( Je suis etê un étudient de française, and not English pupil at scholl. I think that to much are better that [me + Google Translator]!

Comment: OK good luck with the thesis! And I hope someone gives a solution to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Eureka! In LyX 2.2.2 there is a module module, Natbibapa, to do what I want.

In the `document setting` > `module` put that module and ... voila!

In my case, I removed the call to the package `apacite`, because LyX call's before in this way.

Comment: Hi, @Juan Abasolo--I'm trying to solve the same problem and am appreciative of this follow-up. Unfortunately, I can't really understand what you did to fix it beyond adding the module. Would you be willing to clarify? (If it's easier for you, you can clarify in Castilian Spanish and I can translate.) Many thanks.

Comment: Hi,  @CynicallyNaive;
Are you using LyX 2.2.2 or +? 
I solved the problem: deleting all from the LaTeX heading and in the *document* menu, in `document setting` > `module` find the `Natbibapa` module and put it for working with that. Save it.
Now you can use APA format with Natbib options (if you have installed natbib.sty and apacite.sty, of course).
If I can it, I go to put the screenshot of my Lyx
![](http://telegra.ph/file/6e97f02dc41e409df7680.png)

Comment: After activating the module, then proceed as usual with LyX biblio. Under settings, the Bibliography item allows you to choose natbib and specify, say, author-year format. I have a guide about it: http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/Computing-HOWTO/LatexAndLyx/LyX-Bibliography/LyX-Bibliography.pdf